# Why I should reload the page to see the cookie value?

Tags: php, cookies, http-headers

I have this code :

```
<?php
$locale = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
setcookie('locale',$locale, time()+60*60*24*6004, "/", "localhost");
echo $_COOKIE['locale'];
?>
```

I don't understand why I must load the page two times to see the $_COOKIE['locale']; value.

At the first load, I can see the cookie is successfully loaded into my web browser but, I must reload the page to see this value in the webpage.

Comment: `Common Pitfalls:

Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie expires. Expire time is set via the expire parameter. A nice way to debug the existence of cookies is by simply calling print_r($_COOKIE);.`

Answer (score -1):

that's true, you must reload the page, you must reload it by `header("location:".$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]);`